# Can I use NestJS Config Service outside a module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, nestjs

I have a class that is not related to any nest modules. I wanted to import and use my ConfigService inside of this class. Can I do this without adding this class to any module or do I need to have a module in order to use nest generated classes?

Thanks

Comment: `ConfigService` from `@nestjs/config` exists to integrate `dotenv`+`joi` with Nestjs. I don't recommend using it from outside of Nestjs modules

Answer (score 8):

You can create on class like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  static service: ConfigService;

  constructor(service: ConfigService) {
    AppConfig.service = service;
  }

  static get(key: string): any {
    return AppConfig.service.get(key);
  }
}
```

add this class as a provider in your root module `AppModule`,

```
...
providers: [AppConfig],
...
```

now once the app is booted, you can use it as following anywhere inside app,

```
AppConfig.get('database.port');
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It did help. Thanks!

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in this line return AppConfig.service.get(key);

Comment: This code exhibits race condition behavior, not reliable code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Vinayak Sarawagi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850309/985454)'s solution, you can even do this inside your custom ConfigModule:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'

@Injectable()
export class MyConfigService {
  static config: MyConfigService

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    MyConfigService.config = this
  }

  get isDevelopment(): boolean {
    return this.configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'development'
  }
}
```

you can then use whatever private property you have on that service

```
AppConfig.config.isDevelopment
```

*See the linked answer for details how to export the module globally.*

Answer (score -1):

Yep, you can get anything from Nest.js DI container using `app.get` method.

e.g.

`const configService = app.get(ConfigService)`

Comment: Hmmm, but what if I don't have access to app in this class context?. Should I be able to get it working with just `new ConfigService()`?

Comment: Assuming your class has no dependencies that need to be injected, that should be fine. But if it does, then you need the context of the Nest.JS application to do that for you.